# Grounding Circuit with two Power Supplies Wired Together

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, grounding, high-voltage, linear-regulator

I am trying to operate an x-ray tube that requires a high-voltage supply and a lower-voltage filament supply.

The high voltage supply consists of a Cockcroft–Walton voltage multiplier, and the filament supply revolves around an LM338 voltage regulator that steps down the 12 V from the SW transformer to 4 V.

In order to operate it, it requires the HV ground to be directly connected with the lower voltage part, which is not rated for those voltages and will cause damage to the equipment.

To prevent damage I am trying to ground the circuit properly: the - of the SW power supply, the - connected to the filament, and the - of the higher voltage supply are all connected to the earth-ground/0 V of the outlet.
[image]
Would this be the correct wiring? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make a transformer with the required secondary isolation for the heater. I’m concerned that you are working with dangerous voltages but yet do not seem to have a good grasp of electrical concepts. Grounding is not the issue here. I also hope you have adequate protection from the X-rays.

Comment: Hello, why would it note be possible to use the current supply? I am aware of the various dangers of this project and have taken the proper precautions when working with the system.